# How to split and separate variables and constantes from a function as string on java

Tags: java, variables, split, expression

I want to split variable and constants from a given polynomial function (`String` type).

Example: `splitString("4x+6y+7z",var[],const[])`

Result:

```
var[]={x;y,z}
Const[]={4;6,7}
```

Comment: Show your code and tell us why you think it doesn't work

Comment: Nice that you have homework to do and have told us what you need to do. Do you have any specific problem?

Comment: Think guys that's is just a small part of my project !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to separate constants and variables from the string you need to loop through each character of the string and find out whether the character is **Digit** or **Alphabetic**. You can make use of **Character.isDigit()** and **Character.isAlphabetic()** methods to differentiate between the characters.

For example, see below:

```
String s = "4x+6y+7z";

        //some fields will be null, because we don't know how many 
        //constants will be there, same goes for variables array 
        String[] constants = new String[s.length()];

        String[] variables = new String[s.length()]; 

        //loop through the string, length of string             
        for(int i =0, j = 0, k=0 ; i< s.length();i++) {
            if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
                //the character at location ith location of string is Digit
                constants[j] = String.valueOf(s.charAt(i));
                j++; 
            } else if(Character.isAlphabetic(s.charAt(i))) {
                 //the character at location ith location of string is Alphabet
                variables[k] = String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)); 
                k++; 
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(constants));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(variables));
```

You can also make use of ArrayList in java to store those constants and variables in the form of Double and Character. Unlike arrays the size of the list does not have to be declared in advance (above I declared the size of both arrays to the size of input string which obviously results in some null fields in the array which can be avoided in many ones and one of them is using List)

```
String s = "4x+6y+7z";

//list to store constants
List<Double> constantsList = new ArrayList<Double>(); 

//list to store variables 
List<Character> variablesList = new ArrayList<Character>(); 

//loop through length of string         
for(int i =0; i< s.length();i++) {
    if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
        //add constant to the list as Double
        constantsList.add(Double.valueOf(s.charAt(i))); 
    } else if(Character.isAlphabetic(s.charAt(i))) {
        //add variable to the list as double
        variablesList.add(Character.valueOf(s.charAt(i))); 
    }
}

System.out.println(constantsList); 
System.out.println(variablesList);
```

If you wish to have the constants and variables as array then you can convert the lists back to arrays of exact sizes now that you know how many constants and variables are there.

Comment: Thank you It's work with me